# fonttools/fontmake's generated otf-cff2 does not work on Windows

Tags: windows, fonts, opentype

I have generated an otf font using

```
fontmake -o otf-cff2 -g source.glyphs
```

The resulting font works on Linux and Mac and can be opened in online tools
like fontgauntlet, but I cannot open it on Windows (by double-clicking it in
explorer).

- Should windows be able to open/install cff2 fonts?
- If so, what's the problem with a fontmake generated font?

Thanks...

Edit: [FontValidator](https://github.com/HinTak/Font-Validator)  says: **Required table is missing. Font must contain either a glyf, CFF, EBDT or CBDT table.**

There is the `cff2` table though in the font file.

Comment: Just to make sure... have you copied the file to a local disk or are you trying to open it directly from a network share from your Linux system?

Comment: I did copy the font. Also, when I generate otf ( fontmake -o otf -g source.... ) the font works.

Comment: What does [Font Validator](https://github.com/HinTak/Font-Validator) say about these fonts? What is the file-extension of these otf-cff2 fonts? Can you post online an example font? (Add to your comment `@harrymc` for me to be notified.)

Comment: @harrymc : I cannot post the font. I have run FontValidator, and updated the original question.